# How to code a looping error message in a survey app?

Tags: python, loops

I'm very new to coding (Python), and for my first project I'm making a mini-survey programme that tells the user their zodiac sign based on their birthday. I want to put in a looping error message if they key in a non-integer or invalid date, i.e. something that says "invalid birthday, please try again," and repeats over and over until they key in something valid. Problem is I'm not sure what loop to use, and where to put it (at the very end?)

Here's the code for the programme:

```
print('Hello SDSA!')
print('What is your name?')
myname = input()
print('Nice to meet you, ' + myname + '!')
print('How old are you?')
myage = input()
print('Amazing. Could you tell me your birthday?' + '(Please input your birthday in mmdd format.)')
bd = input()
if int(bd) in range(321,332) or int(bd) in range(401,421):
    print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Aries!")
    zod = 'Aries'
elif int(bd) in range(421,431) or int(bd) in range(501,522):
    print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Taurus!")
    zod = 'Taurus'
elif int(bd) in range(522,531) or int(bd) in range(601,622):
    print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Gemini!")
    zod = 'Gemini'
elif int(bd) in range(622,631) or int(bd) in range(701,723):
    print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Cancer!")
    zod = 'Cancer'
elif int(bd) in range(723,731) or int(bd) in range(801,823):
    print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Leo!")
    zod = 'Leo'
elif int(bd) in range(823,832) or int(bd) in range(901,923):
    print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Virgo!")
    zod = 'Virgo'
elif int(bd) in range(923,931) or int(bd) in range(1001,1023):
    print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Libra!")
    zod = 'Libra'
elif int(bd) in range(1023,1031) or int(bd) in range(1101,1122):
    print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Scorpio!")
    zod = 'Scorpio'
elif int(bd) in range(1122,1131) or int(bd) in range(1201,1222):
    print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Sagittarius!")
    zod = 'Sagittarius'
elif int(bd) in range(1222,1231) or int(bd) in range(101,121):
    print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Capricorn!")
    zod = 'Capricorn'
elif int(bd) in range(121,131) or int(bd) in range(201,220):
    print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Aquarius!")
    zod = 'Aquarius'
elif int(bd) in range(220,230) or int(bd) in range(301,321):
    print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Pisces!")
    zod = 'Pisces'
```

Comment: Throw all your if/elif statements in a while loop with a bool set to true.  Add an else condition that does whatever you want when the input is invalid.  Then add a statement that sets your bool value to false inside each of the valid if conditions so that the loop will be broken

Answer (score 1):

For if an answer is a digit there is a build in python function somethinghere.isdigit() for instance :

```
myage = input()
if myage.isdigit() == True:
    print("Its a number")
else:
    print("Its not a number")
```

For the date issue

```
import datetime
while True:
    myage = input()
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(myage, '%Y-%m-%d')
        ### anything to do after like checking zodiacs######
        break
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate it using the datetime strptime function, which can take in a string and compare it to the datetime format you want.  In this cse %m%d for 2 digit month and 2 digit date (with leading zeros).

You can create an while loop that will go on until the condition is met.  In this case if the input is not in the correct format, the valid_db line will fail and throw a ValueError.  This exception is passed on and the loop is started again.  If the strptime() function succeeds (they input the date the way you wanted) the break statement will exit the loop and continue.

```
import datetime
while True:
    try:
         bd = input('Amazing. Could you tell me your birthday?' + '(Please input your birthday in mmdd format.)')
         valid_db = datetime.datetime.strptime(bd, '%m%d')
         break
    except ValueError:
       pass
```

Comment: Please explain your code to make your answer more likely to be accepted

Answer (score 0):

Nice work. Try puting your code in a `while loop` like this:

```
print('Amazing. Could you tell me your birthday?' + '(Please input your birthday in mmdd format.)')   
while True:      
    bd = input()
    if int(bd) in range(321,332) or int(bd) in range(401,421):
        print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Aries!")
        zod = 'Aries'
        break
    elif int(bd) in range(421,431) or int(bd) in range(501,522):
        print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Taurus!")
        zod = 'Taurus'
        break
    # The rest of your code goes here
    else: 
        print("Invalid birthday, please try again")
```

Do not forget to put a `break` statement after the correct responses, otherwise you will be stuck in an [infinite loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop).

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way

```
print('Hello SDSA!')
print('What is your name?')
myname = input()
print('Nice to meet you, ' + myname + '!')
print('How old are you?')
myage = input()
print('Amazing. Could you tell me your birthday?',)
invalid_birthday = True
while invalid_birthday:
    invalid_birthday = False
    print('(Please input your birthday in mmdd format.)')
    bd_input = input()
    bd = int(bd_input) if bd_input.isdigit() else 0
    if bd in range(321,332) or bd in range(401,421):
        print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Aries!")
        zod = 'Aries'
    elif bd in range(421,431) or bd in range(501,522):
        print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Taurus!")
        zod = 'Taurus'
    elif bd in range(522,531) or bd in range(601,622):
        print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Gemini!")
        zod = 'Gemini'
    elif bd in range(622,631) or bd in range(701,723):
        print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Cancer!")
        zod = 'Cancer'
    elif bd in range(723,731) or bd in range(801,823):
        print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Leo!")
        zod = 'Leo'
    elif bd in range(823,832) or bd in range(901,923):
        print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Virgo!")
        zod = 'Virgo'
    elif bd in range(923,931) or bd in range(1001,1023):
        print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Libra!")
        zod = 'Libra'
    elif bd in range(1023,1031) or bd in range(1101,1122):
        print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Scorpio!")
        zod = 'Scorpio'
    elif bd in range(1122,1131) or bd in range(1201,1222):
        print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Sagittarius!")
        zod = 'Sagittarius'
    elif bd in range(1222,1231) or bd in range(101,121):
        print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Capricorn!")
        zod = 'Capricorn'
    elif bd in range(121,131) or bd in range(201,220):
        print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Aquarius!")
        zod = 'Aquarius'
    elif bd in range(220,230) or bd in range(301,321):
        print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Pisces!")
        zod = 'Pisces'
    else:
        invalid_birthday = True
        print ("Invalid birthday, please try again.")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can put the loop at the start.

```
while True:
    print('Hello SDSA!')
    print('What is your name?')
    myname = input()
    print('Nice to meet you, ' + myname + '!')
    print('How old are you?')
    myage = input()
    print('Amazing. Could you tell me your birthday?' + '(Please input your birthday in mmdd format.)')
    bd = input()
    if int(bd) in range(321,332) or int(bd) in range(401,421):
        print("You're a " + myage + "-year-old Aries!")
        zod = 'Aries'
    # rest of your code here...

    else:
        print ('Invalid Inputs. Please try again')
```